# Add compiler options when spring-boot-maven-plugin is used

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I want to use the jackson module parameter-names with Java 8 in my spring boot application. I need to provide the option "-parameters" to the compiler. Could you please let me know how to do this in pom.xml for the spring boot plug-in spring-boot-maven-plugin.

I found only following answer ([How to compile Spring Boot applications with Java 8 --parameter flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845676/how-to-compile-spring-boot-applications-with-java-8-parameter-flag/31846371#31846371)), but the answer refers to different plug-in.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried? That's actually the right answer, the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` does not do any compilation at all and does not support/require/need that parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. This was my mistake that it did not work for me earlier (the class was included in an external module managed by separate pom.xml).

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot relies on maven-compiler-plugin. Check Spring Boot parent pom. Or check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49316086/4470135)