# Should Feign interface has @PathVariable and @RequestParam annotations with stated names to work?

Tags: java, request, feign, declarative, openfeign

In fresh openfeign library (version 3.1.3) there is a check in [PathVariableParameterProcessor](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/blob/v3.1.3/spring-cloud-openfeign-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/openfeign/annotation/PathVariableParameterProcessor.java#L52), that verifies, that arguments with `@PathVariable` annotation should have name attribute filled. Similar check exists in RequestParamParameterProcessor.

In [openfeign official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html) there is no sign of that rule, there are examples with both named and unnamed annotations

In [one of the issues](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/861) of spring-cloud-netflix library (that as I heard is an openfeign's  predecessor) people also recommend just declare names of parameters.

In my project I had declared openfeign interfaces without explicitly specified parameter names (e.g. `@PathVariable String someId`), and it was working until now. Now I get exception coming from check stated above.

```
... org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.mycompany.client.MyClient': Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: PathVariable annotation was empty on param 0.
...
                    Caused by:
                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: PathVariable annotation was empty on param 0.
                        at feign.Util.checkState(Util.java:122)
                        at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.annotation.PathVariableParameterProcessor.processArgument(PathVariableParameterProcessor.java:52)
                        at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringMvcContract.processAnnotationsOnParameter(SpringMvcContract.java:280)
                        at feign.Contract$BaseContract.parseAndValidateMetadata(Contract.java:126)
                        at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringMvcContract.parseAndValidateMetadata(SpringMvcContract.java:193)
                        at feign.Contract$BaseContract.parseAndValidateMetadata(Contract.java:65)
                        at feign.ReflectiveFeign$ParseHandlersByName.apply(ReflectiveFeign.java:151)
                        at feign.ReflectiveFeign.newInstance(ReflectiveFeign.java:49)
                        at feign.Feign$Builder.target(Feign.java:268)
                        at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.DefaultTargeter.target(DefaultTargeter.java:30)
                        at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.getTarget(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:451)
                        at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.getObject(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:402)
                        at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsRegistrar.lambda$registerFeignClient$0(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:235)
                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1249)
                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1191)
                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
                        ... 130 more
```

Client interface api example

```
    @GetMapping("/{entityType}/{entityId}")
    List<Document> getDocs(
            @PathVariable String entityType,
            @PathVariable String entityId,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String ownerId,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String q);
```

Can somebody explain, is it really mandatory routine to write names yourself, or is there another way to automate it?

Comment: Please also add you interface,. What values has `@RequestMapping` ?

Comment: @artiomi, I've updated my question with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon related question on SO and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44391584/2185612) kind of answers my question too.

To formulate answer to my post:

- Yes, it is mandatory by default
- Yes, there is a way to automate it by configuring compilation, to preserve original method argument names in .class files and let feign's StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer resolve these names by reflection

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to write names of path variable is mandatory. There is no info about this in official documentation of [Spring OpenFeign](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/) also. So, use with name of parameter. `@PathVariable("someId") String someId`

Answer (score 0):

In order to use e.g. `@PathVariable String someId)` without an explicit name parameter just apply `Spring Boot’s Gradle plugin`  or `spring-boot-starter-parent` to your project.

It'll add `-parameters` to the compilation section in your project build tool which is required for such an approach.

More details from the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints):

> To let the input be mapped to the operation method’s parameters, Java
> code that implements an endpoint should be compiled with -parameters,
> and Kotlin code that implements an endpoint should be compiled with
> -java-parameters. This will happen automatically if you use Spring Boot’s Gradle plugin or if you use Maven and
> spring-boot-starter-parent.